# Are there dictionaries giving knowledge on countability of nouns?

Tags: dictionaries

Is there any dictionary, online or physical, that gives information on whether a noun is countable or not?

Comment: Macmillan is the best one that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com) does what you're looking for, I believe. For an example, [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/water_1) is their page on "water", which says "1 [uncountable] a liquid without colour[...]"

If the noun is countable (for instance, [table](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/table_1)), The Oxford Learner's Dictionary will simply not mention it - so assume that it's countable unless otherwise stated.

Comment: I wish to vote you up more than once! Thanks so much.

Comment: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/water) is just as good. The [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/water#Noun) does do. And plenty of others....